# Count function in R

Tags: r

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("13/09/14", "14/09/14", "15/09/14", 
"16/08/14", "17/08/14", "18/08/14", "23/08/14", "24/08/14", "25/08/14", 
"30/08/14", "31/08/14"), class = "factor"), HomeTeam = structure(c(1L, 
8L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 9L, 12L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 
17L, 7L, 16L, 18L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 17L, 20L, 2L, 
8L, 18L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 11L, 7L), .Label = c("Arsenal", 
"Aston Villa", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", 
"Hull", "Leicester", "Liverpool", "Man City", "Man United", "Newcastle", 
"QPR", "Southampton", "Stoke", "Sunderland", "Swansea", "Tottenham", 
"West Brom", "West Ham"), class = "factor"), AwayTeam = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 17L, 7L, 2L, 16L, 18L, 14L, 10L, 4L, 12L, 8L, 20L, 1L, 19L, 
3L, 15L, 11L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 4L, 15L, 5L, 16L, 19L, 14L, 7L, 1L, 
9L, 10L, 17L, 3L, 2L, 12L, 8L, 18L, 6L, 13L, 20L), .Label = c("Arsenal", 
"Aston Villa", "Burnley", "Chelsea", "Crystal Palace", "Everton", 
"Hull", "Leicester", "Liverpool", "Man City", "Man United", "Newcastle", 
"QPR", "Southampton", "Stoke", "Sunderland", "Swansea", "Tottenham", 
"West Brom", "West Ham"), class = "factor"), FTR = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "D", "H"), class = "factor"), 
Referee = structure(c(4L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 1L, 12L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 
11L, 9L, 6L, 8L, 5L, 15L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
10L, 16L, 14L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 13L, 8L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 2L, 11L, 
3L, 1L, 13L, 7L), .Label = c("A Taylor", "C Foy", "C Pawson", 
"J Moss", "K Friend", "L Mason", "M Atkinson", "M Clattenburg", 
"M Dean", "M Jones", "M Oliver", "N Swarbrick", "P Dowd", 
"P Tierney", "R East", "R Madley"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
"HomeTeam", "AwayTeam", "FTR", "Referee"), row.names = c(NA, 
40L), class = "data.frame")
```

In the above dataset I am trying to find out the referee who served the most number of matches for each team. For example, which guy refereed for Aston Villa the most in home games and in away games and both.

Sorry about me being blunt with my question. I did make an attempt.
In order to find out how many times referee J Moss refereed for Arsenal I tried this,

```
awayref<-nrow(awayref<-(filter(fd,fd$Referee=='J Moss',fd$AwayTeam=='Arsenal')))
homeref<-nrow(hf<-(filter(fd,fd$Referee=='J Moss',fd$HomeTeam=='Arsenal')))
View(total<-homeref+awayref)
```

I needed some help with looping it to include all referees and all teams.

Comment: It would have been better if you have also showed the expected output.

Comment: Or some effort of your own in solving your issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
 tbl1 <- table(df1$Referee)
 tbl1[which.max(tbl1)]
```